# Image not uploaded on server in iOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, image-uploading, afnetworking-2

i want to upload an image on to server my image view image for that i write a code like as

```
UIImage *image = self.uploadImageView.image;
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"http://199.16.128.49/~gzfknsfg/webservices/insert_image.php?foldername=comm_image&img_name=iosimage.jpeg" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:@"name"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
}
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

then i got result success from above code but image not uploading in to server.
And my `php` side code like as

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST['foldername']) && isset($_REQUEST['img_name']))
 {
 $foldername=$_REQUEST["foldername"];
 $img_name=$_FILES["img_name"]["name"];
 $tmp=$_FILES["img_name"]["tmp_name"];
 $targetfile="$foldername/".$img_name;
 move_uploaded_file($tmp,$targetfile);
 $json_result= array("status"=>"success" , "data"=>"file uploaded");
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Change `[formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:@"name"];` to `[formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:@"img_name"];`

Comment: @iphonic then also image is not uploading. but i always got success message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the following line

```
[formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:@"name"];
```

to

```
[formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"img_name" fileName:@"iosimage.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
```

and it should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your php web-service API return success to all call it only checking folder name and image name.

Comment: web-service is not checking image data or not checking image upload progress to return success message.

Comment: is that php file still online?

Comment: @AndreSlotta yes it is online

Comment: yes, you can just check this url in your browser
http://199.16.128.49/~gzfknsfg/webservices/insert_image.php?foldername=comm_image&img_name=iosimage.jpeg